# IIS Header Information in WCF Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Is there a way to get IIS header information in wcf call? Basically i need to get the device type e.g. Mobile Phone (iOS, Android).

How would i know if the requested WCF call is from android or iphone?

Comment: There is no way to get this information from WCF request, because it does not have browser header. You will have to provide device as additional parameter, or use different endpoints for different devices

Comment: what would be benefit of using different end points for different devices ?

Comment: You always can get EndpointAddress from OperationContext, so there is no need to modify contracts.

Comment: basically our client is not .net based. they are android or iOS. and they dont use any kind of binding. our clients are just calling this wcf service as web http request.our wcf is restful service

Comment: In my MVC web service I use Context.Request.UserAgent to get the user agent name. Context.Request.Browser is also an other option. Is this not applicable for you?

Answer (score -1):

Try looking in strontium WCF REST request to the server where the request header is transmitted